# Settings -> messages screen is empty

Tags: iphone, messages

Had an iPhone 6, created an iTunes backup, restored it to new iPhone 6s.
Both devices are managed by my company.

On the 6s, iMessage has a red exclamation mark, telling me I have been logged out of iMessage. To fix this, i shall go to "settings -> messages" (may be called differently, translated this from German Einstellungen -> Nachrichten).

This screen is completely empty with the only thing showing is the "

How can I reconnect my phone to iMessage?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the settings were intentionally hidden by our IT department using AirWatch.